# Stackoverflow podcast intro music

Tags: discussion, podcast

Can we start a campaign to change the Stack Overflow podcast introduction music?

The saxophone number is very cheesy and would want something that does not sound like it came from a 4th grade music class...

**Edit**

With the announcement of a [possible new format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42247/what-ideas-are-out-there-for-the-new-podcast) to the podcast.  Can we start a grassroots movement to change the music or possibly creating their own theme song.

Comment: And I thought that was kind of cultural thing or something. I was like "Oh that music is terrible, mhhh perhaps is considered *elegant*  within the US natives, let's respect their idiosyncrasy"

Comment: I never hear it - the first thing I do when I start the SO podcast is fast-forward until about 1:10 to skip all the ads.

Comment: As tempted as I am to skip the ads, it just feels wrong. It pays IT Conversations bills and its not like they are that bad.

Comment: @AnonJr - I am not against advertisements, I just think the music is horrible...haha!

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't it come from IT Conversations?

Comment: Yes, it is part of the IT conversations portion of the podcast.

Answer (score 1):

Before Jeff & Joel join IT Conversations, I believe Joel said that he dislikes theme music on podcasts, and that he didn't want any.  I remember someone actually created a theme song for the podcast, and they used it once, but Joel said he didn't want to use it regularly.

Comment: Did they actually play it? I thought they just mentioned that it was created but didn't actually play it at all.

Comment: Yeah, if I remember correctly, they played it at the end of the episode.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the intro song be replaced with [one of my favourites](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MKrYxtCLyY). It's guaranteed to be liked equally by everyone who hears it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the music you're referring to is the IT Conversations theme, some of the podcasts hosted there have their own theme music - I'm thinking of 'Tech Nation' with Moira Gunn, which has a fetching piano track - so IT Conversations podcasts obviously support nested theme music. I suggest some Aphex Twin.

Comment: Jeff and Joel will have to pay royalties to Aphex Twim.