# What ideas are out there for the new podcast?

Tags: discussion, podcast

Joel published on [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/podcast-future/) his request for ideas for the new podcast.

So, any ideas?

Comment: It's going to be New Coke, isn't it?

Comment: A year later and there's nothing happening. Even Joel's tweets are mostly promotions for some stackexchange site. Things are getting boring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have special podcasters on (not guest). These special podcasters would be the other SO Valued Associates:

- [Kevin Montrose](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-000004/)
- [Geoff Dalgas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00003/)
- [Jarrod Dixon](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00002/)

They would either take the place of Jeff and/or Joel (not permanently of course) or podcast along side them.

Also after reading some of the comments on the blog post I would like to quote [Bill Paetzke](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/podcast-future/#comment-45019):

> If you add guests, please make sure they mix well with your dynamic–someone with a sense of humor. You’ve had a few dull guests in the past. Perhaps stick to guests who are fellow software entrepreneurs or software developers (regardless of employment) who blog well. Or make a web form for listeners to submit topic proposals and be guests.

Finally the main thing that has kept me listening to these podcast is **YOU GUYS** (Jeff & Joel). You're funny and easily likable. If one of you takes an extended break `<cough>`Joel`</cough>` I'll probably quit listening. It just wouldn't be right.

Comment: +1: I would love to hear the other members of the team more often

Answer (score 7):

Please don't get rid of all the technical discussion.

Answer (score 3):

I feel that if Joel & Jeff take the trouble to engage a guest they should act like talk show hosts and let the guest chat a lot more on his or her subject. Yes, some guests are not as verbal as we would like but still. I feel that J&J tend to drown or dampen the guest with their stuff. We can listen to their stuff, on podcasts that do not contain a guest.

Perhaps J&J could go on a course of "How to make you guest feel at home, and how to keep them talking"

My 2 cents worth

Answer (score 2):

More interviews/guests.

Answer (score 2):

A narrative around the business of starting up / running a technology company.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't change anything

You just need to read the incredible feedback received on the blog post to see that the podcast is awesome as is.
Jeff+Joel are great and the format is a perfect mixture of programming culture and fun.