# Why did the SO podcast stop?

Tags: discussion, podcast

The SO podcast was an interesting podcast but it seems it stopped. Last thing I remember hearing was Joel saying there's nothing interesting to talk about and he had quit writing blogs, articles and such.

Is it OK to continue the podcast without him (no disrespect)? Like interviewing some of the SO developers and discuss the challenges they met? Interview some of the very active users and discuss what they think and why they are active? What are the some of the future plans?

You can add your suggestions in the comments or answers.

It doesn't have to be regular like every week. Just don't kill it.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42247/what-ideas-are-out-there-for-the-new-podcast

Comment: It got closed and deleted.

Comment: 133 comments and 5 months later, I don't see any sign of life. Joel said it will be back up in April. Based on the comments I read, most people liked it. I liked it. You can always freshen something up without killing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bring back the podcast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79649/bring-back-the-podcast)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It started again in [April, 2011](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/podcast-88/).